# In Spring, how to flag transaction info?

Tags: java, spring, aop

I need to somehow flag a transaction. Need some method like: TransactionAspectSupport.setData(someObject); Then till the transaction is alive I would like to be able to read those data.

I need it to check in Aspect class that some operation on current transaction has been already proceeded.

EDIT:
To illustrate what I mean. Let's have two classes.

Service class:

```
class Service {

@Transactional
public void serviceA(){
    // do something
    serviceB();
}

@Transactional
public void serviceB(){
    // do something
}
}
```

Aspect class:

```
@Aspect
class ServiceAspect {

@Pointcut("execution(public * service*)")
private void checkTransaction(){};

@Around("checkTransaction()")
public Object _checkTransaction(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

    if (!isTransactionFlagged())
        doTheCheckingJob()

    transactionInfo.setData(Boolean.True);
}


private boolean isTransactionFlagged() {
    if (transactionInfo.getData != null)
        return true;
    return false;
}
}
```

As you can see I need to flag the transaction somehow, so the aspect do not fire multiple times in one transaction. But still need the aspect to fire for each service method. Just not fire on the inner call of service method.

Comment: I don't know the context, but maybe you can solve your problem by creating another transaction after your method call so it won't rollback everything when an exception occurs. `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Do you need to see the changes made in a specific transaction while they are not committed yet? What do you mean by *read those data*?

Comment: There is an Aspect class that executes multiple times in one transaction. Because we are calling more service methods in one transaction. And I need to somehow know that Aspect methods have been already executed. So I just need some method to put my own object into TransactionInfo or into TransactionStatus. Let's say it would be a Boolean isTransactionChecked. The propagation would not help me in that case.

Comment: What make you unable to put this logic inside your code ?  , you can use spring to force use of the same transaction  over all methods and put your boolean or any data into your own singleton.

Comment: Have added some code to illustrate what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want without manual bookkeeping using `cflow()` or `cflowbelow()` pointcuts. Unfortunately they are [unavailable in Spring AOP](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-designators), but if you configure Spring to use [AspectJ with LTW (load-time weaving)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj) instead, you can use them.

If you want to stick with Spring AOP, though, you indeed need to do manual bookkeeping, e.g. using a `ThreadLocal` member (assuming that each transaction is executed in a separate thread) or whatever else is appropriate. But maybe there are on-board means in the Spring framework to enable the behaviour you need. I am not a Spring user, so I cannot help you there, though. I only know about AOP.

Feel free to ask follow-up questions and/or provide more code, then I can get more concrete.